# iOS Validation failed -> Bundle is invalid (Xcode 6.2, iOS 8.2)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Apple released a new xcode today and after upgrading to 6.2 I can no longer submit apps to iTunesConnect. When running Validate I receive the following error.

This bundle is invalid. New apps and updates submitted ... must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode. Do not submit apps built with beta software.

I'm not using anything that is better, just software that is a couple of hours old. Any ideas how to fix this?

My Deployment Target is: 8.2

Build Settings > Base SDK > Latest iOS (iOS 8.2)

Thanks

Comment: Can you check the build version of your Xcode? Newest release version should be 6C131e

Comment: @LoVo Yes, I'm using 6C131e

Comment: Ok what about you OS Version? OS X 10.10.2 (14C109) ?

Comment: @LoVo 10.10.3 Updated this morning

Comment: I might be wrong but when i check the Mac Appstore the current version is still 10.10.2, maybe the 10.10.3 is still beta? That would explain the error message you get

Comment: Referring to the Technical Note TN2318 here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2318/_index.html you shouldn't use neither OSX Beta nor Xcode Beta

Comment: You are correct. I was off of the OSX beta program for a while and somehow my system jumped back on. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. And my solution is: delete your Xcode app and reinstall from app store! Everything works as before.

Try it, maybe it works for you too.