# Xcode 6.2 gives "This bundle is invalid." after upgrading

Tags: ios, itunes-store, xcode-6.2

Right after updating to Xcode 6.2 which was released hours ago, my app stops passing the validation phase. It shows "This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 5.1.1 or higher and iOS 7 SDK. Do not submit apps built with beta software."
[image]

Well....my Xcode is an official release by Apple and its version is 6.2.
[image]

Is this a bug or?

Thanks!

Comment: Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28952740/3985749) any use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my own solution. Don't waste your time setting configurations etc. What I did was pretty "brutal". Just delete/uninstall the Xcode app and download it from the App Store again. Then it works as before, as it should.